# Angular PrimeNG how to get a list of options by clicking on the input filed instead of button?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I am trying to rebuild a dropdown and I faced some issues.
I am using the **basic** dropdown on my project and I need to see the whole list of options on clicking the input field. I cannot use the arrow icon from the **second example**. I already tried to use the following events from the documentation: onDropdownClick, onSelect, and [dropdown]="true" but they do not work, I do not know why.  Could you give me some advice on how to solve this issue and get the options on click, please?
Best regards.

[Here is the documentation I have used](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete)

[Here is the code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-ttsftq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { SelectItemGroup } from 'primeng/api';
import { CountryService } from './countryservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [CountryService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  country: any;

  countries: any[];

  filteredCountriesSingle: any[];

  filteredCountriesMultiple: any[];

  brands: string[] = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'Honda', 'Jaguar', 'Mercedes', 'Renault', 'Volvo', 'VW'];

  filteredBrands: any[];

  brand: string;

  constructor(private countryService: CountryService) { }

  filterCountrySingle(event) {
    let query = event.query;
    this.countryService.getCountries().then(countries => {
      this.filteredCountriesSingle = this.filterCountry(query, countries);
    });
  }

  filterCountryMultiple(event) {
    let query = event.query;
    this.countryService.getCountries().then(countries => {
      this.filteredCountriesMultiple = this.filterCountry(query, countries);
    });
  }

  filterCountry(query, countries: any[]): any[] {
    //in a real application, make a request to a remote url with the query and return filtered results, for demo we filter at client side
    let filtered: any[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      let country = countries[i];
      if (country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
        filtered.push(country);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  }

  filterBrands(event) {
    this.filteredBrands = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.brands.length; i++) {
      let brand = this.brands[i];
      if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
        this.filteredBrands.push(brand);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working in the Stackblitz. Maybe try restarting your app?

Comment: you mean the basic dropdown not advanced?

Comment: all 3 dropdowns appear to be working as expected, including the advanced